# jsf multiple instances managed bean for multiple tabs

Tags: jsf, tabs, managed-bean, multiple-instances

There is a managed bean(DemoManagedBean.java) which holds some data on the (sample.xhtml)XHTML page.

There is a redirection link in the sample.xhtml which opens a new tab of the same page(sample.xhtml) but with different data loaded.

Issue - since there is only one instance of the DemoManagedBean.java, therefore not able to process anything further i.e; changes on one tab affect all the other tabs.

Is there a way so that I can have a multiple instances for every tab holding the data for the particular tabs?

Thanks,

Dinesh

Comment: _since there is only one instance of the DemoManagedBean.java_ Are you using Singleton pattern or something? Post your code..

Comment: I guess managedbeans of JSF are singleton by default.

Comment: No, they are by default definitely not singletons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control that by setting the right bean **scope**. In your particular case, you need to put the bean in the request scope or in the view scope, depending on if you need a per-view based state or not.

Using the standard JSF bean management API, that would be just this (no XML needed!):

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DemoManagedBean {
    // ...
}
```

When the `@XxxScoped` scope annotation is not specified, it defaults to `@NoneScope`. Your description however matches the session or application scope. Perhaps you've explicitly set the `@SessionScoped` or `@ApplicationScoped` annotation while not really understanding what you were actually doing. Or perhaps you're for some reason using Spring to manage beans, a Spring `@Controller` without any explicit scope specified defaults to application scope.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

Comment: I tried using @ViewScoped but there were some issues. FYI the redirection to new tab is also done from a method in the same bean. Can you point me to any samples?

Comment: Why are you not describing "some issues" in detail? Don't you want to get help on that or so?

Comment: Apologies @BalusC, will get back with more details.

Comment: Many thanks @BalusC... Its working now... Dunno what I did wrong the last time.